# sas data _null_, formats & put statement outputting extra line break

Tags: sas

I'm trying to create a report table similar to what is created in this paper: 
http://www.lexjansen.com/wuss/2004/data_presentation/c_dp_creating_custom_tables_.pdf

However, for some reason, the categorical (i.e. formatted) variables in the table are outputting an extra line after each subcategory.

The code used in the paper:

```
data _null_;
 set Table_DS;
 by entry;

 file out print header=hdr linesleft=remain;

 * --- Report Body;
 if first.entry then put /@&COL1 entry entry.;
 else if entry=3 then put @&COL1 +3 gender gender.;
 else if entry=4 then put @&COL1 +3 race race.; 
 put @&COL2 statc statc.
 @&COL3 p1
 @&COL4 p2
 @&COL5 p3;

 * --- Footer;
 *Note: Cutoff value depends on the number;
 * of lines required for the footer;
 if last or remain < 9 then link ftr;
 return;
 * ----- PUT HEADER;
 hdr:
 ...Insert titles...
 ...Insert column headers...
 return;
 * ----- PUT FOOTER;
 ftr:
 ...Insert footnotes...
 ...Begin a new page...
 return;
run;
```

My code:

```
data _null_;
 set Table_DS end=last;
 by entry;
 file print header=hdr linesleft=remain;
 * --- Report Body;
 if first.entry then put /@ &COL1 entry entry.;
 if entry=1 then put @ &COL1 +3 lineno sex.;
 if entry=2 then put @ &COL1 +3 lineno race.; 
 if entry=3 then put @ &COL1 +3 lineno ethnic.;
 if entry=6 then put @ &COL1 +3 lineno creatcat.;
 if entry=7 then put @ &COL1 +3 lineno admitdx.;
 put @ &COL2 statc statc.
     @ &COL3 p1
     @ &COL4 p2
     @ &COL5 p3;
 if last or remain < 4 then link ftr;
 return;
 hdr: 
  put
 @1 'Table 4: Demographic and Baseline Characteristics'
 /@1 '(ITT analysis set)'
 /@1 '________________________________________________________________________________________________'
 /@1 'Subject Stratum: All Strata'
 /@56 'Group A       Group B       Total'
 /@56 '(N=294)       (N=285)       (N=579)'
 /@1 '________________________________________________________________________________________________';
return;
 ftr:
  put
   @1 '________________________________________________________________________________________________'
   /@1 "Using &ds data set from &deldate";
 return;
 return;
run;
```

Selected output from my code:

```
Table 4: Demographic and Baseline Characteristics
(ITT analysis set)
________________________________________________________________________________________________
Subject Stratum: All Strata
                                                       Group A       Group B    Total
                                                       (N=294)       (N=285)       (N=579)
________________________________________________________________________________________________

       Sex                          

                                         N             294           285           579
          Female
                                         n (%)         78 ( 26.5%)   80 ( 28.1%)   158 ( 27.3%)

       Race                         

                                         N             293           280           573
          White                         
                                         n (%)         289 ( 98.6%)  277 ( 98.9%)  566 ( 98.8%)
          Black or African American     
                                         n (%)         2 (  0.7%)    0 (N/A)       2 (  0.3%)
          Asian                         
                                         n (%)         1 (  0.3%)    0 (N/A)       1 (  0.2%)
          American Indian/Alaskan Native
                                         n (%)         0 (N/A)       1 (  0.4%)    1 (  0.2%)
          Other                         
                                         n (%)         1 (  0.3%)    2 (  0.7%)    3 (  0.5%)

       Ethnicity                    

                                         N             293           281           574
          Not Hispanic/Latino
                                         n (%)         284 ( 96.9%)  266 ( 94.7%)  550 ( 95.8%)
          Hispanic/Latino    
                                         n (%)         9 (  3.1%)    15 (  5.3%)   24 (  4.2%)

       Age (yrs)                    
                                         N             294           285           579
                                         Mean          61.5          62.1          61.8
                                         SD            9.2           9.2           9.2
                                         Median        61.0          61.0          61.0
                                         Minimum       34.0          36.0          34.0
                                         Maximum       81.0          85.0          85.0

       BMI (kg/m^2)                 
                                         N             290           280           570
                                         Mean          28.8          28.9          28.9
                                         SD            4.8           4.7           4.7
                                         Median        28.0          28.4          28.2
                                         Minimum       18.2          18.7          18.2
                                         Maximum       46.5          48.2          48.2
```

I've looked over the entire paper and compared our codes, but I cannot figure out why the formatted categorical variables are tabbing the stats to the next line while the continuous stats are printing without any extra lines in between.

Here is the sample data:

```
P1  lineno  statc   P2  P3  entry
294 -1  1   285 579 1
78 ( 26.5%) 1   7   80 ( 28.1%) 158 ( 27.3%)    1
293 -1  1   280 573 2
289 ( 98.6%)    1   7   277 ( 98.9%)    566 ( 98.8%)    2
2 ( 0.7%)   2   7   0 (N/A) 2 ( 0.3%)   2
1 ( 0.3%)   3   7   0 (N/A) 1 ( 0.2%)   2
0 (N/A) 4   7   1 ( 0.4%)   1 ( 0.2%)   2
1 ( 0.3%)   5   7   2 ( 0.7%)   3 ( 0.5%)   2
293 -1  1   281 574 3
284 ( 96.9%)    0   7   266 ( 94.7%)    550 ( 95.8%)    3
9 ( 3.1%)   1   7   15 ( 5.3%)  24 ( 4.2%)  3
294 .   1   285 579 4
61.5    .   2   62.1    61.8    4
9.2 .   3   9.2 9.2 4
61  .   4   61  61  4
34  .   5   36  34  4
81  .   6   85  85  4
290 .   1   280 570 5
28.8    .   2   28.9    28.9    5
4.8 .   3   4.7 4.7 5
28  .   4   28.4    28.2    5
18.2    .   5   18.7    18.2    5
46.5    .   6   48.2    48.2    5
```

Comment: What happens if you put an `@` symbol (to prevent the put statement from finishing with a new-line character) at the end of this statement: `@ &COL5 p3 @;`?

Comment: As an aside: this is an interesting approach to use to learn the basics of reporting in SAS, but as it stands it's not something I'd use in production.  `PROC REPORT` is able to produce the same table, or close enough, with a lot less custom work, and if you do need something custom you can do a lot better than this by using a `proc template` table or even just macrotizing the above.

Comment: @RobertPenridge It seems to have shifted the 'N' row down 1 line and therefore all n(%) are shifted down 1 line as well. Also, the continuous var descriptives have all disappeared except for the last line of 'Maximum.' I'll keep playing with the pointer, but I might take Joe's advice and look into using proc report. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is found by analyzing the difference in the codes above.  It's a bit hard to do this empirically (as you don't provide sample data, so I can't be 100% sure what the dataset looks like), but nonetheless:

Your code:

```
if first.entry then put /@ &COL1 entry entry.;
 if entry=1 then put @ &COL1 +3 lineno sex.;
 if entry=2 then put @ &COL1 +3 lineno race.; 
 if entry=3 then put @ &COL1 +3 lineno ethnic.;
 if entry=6 then put @ &COL1 +3 lineno creatcat.;
 if entry=7 then put @ &COL1 +3 lineno admitdx.;
```

The original code from the paper:

```
 if first.entry then put /@&COL1 entry entry.;
 else if entry=3 then put @&COL1 +3 gender gender.;
 else if entry=4 then put @&COL1 +3 race race.;
```

On that first row, `first.entry`, it puts the entry (`Sex` etc.), and then *processes another line*, `if entry=1 then put @ &COL1 +3 lineno sex.;`  I assume `lineno` is probably missing on those rows (or is a 0 or something else that is set to missing by the `sex.` format).

In the original paper, that was never executed for that `first.entry` line, as it is in an `else` block.

Comment: Unfortunately adding the appropriate 'else if' to the lineno statements produced the same results as just using 'if'.